# Proposition 5.7.1 in Blitzstein and Hwang

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am a little confused over a detail in the following result: [image]

In particular, my question is on the details of why the probability of a tie $X_i = X_j$ is $0$, the explanation for which I'm not satisfied by in the proof above. I can see why $X_i \equiv X_j$ cannot be true just from the independence condition (i.e. they are not the same function $S \to \mathbb{R}$ where $S$ is the sample space). However, I'm having trouble *justifying* why the probability of them agreeing at all is necessarily $0$.

If $A = \{k \in \mathbb{R}: k = X_i(s) = X_j(s) \ \text{for some } s \in S\}$ is countable, this is clear since we can just use the $\sigma$-subadditivity of the probability measure to deduce:

$$P(X_i = X_j) = P(\bigcup_{k \in A}\{X_i = X_j = k\}) \leq \sum_{k \in A}P(X_i = X_j = k) = 0 $$
where the last equality follows by the fact that the probability of a continuous random variable equaling a particular value $k$ is $0$. However, what if $A$, as defined above, is uncountable? That is, what do we do if $X_i$ is not $X_j$ (i.e. there exists some $s \in S$ for which $X_i(s) \neq X_j(s)$) but yet $A$ is uncountable? How do we prove $P(X_i = X_j) = 0$ in this case?

I apologize if this question seems elementary or is trivially obvious - maybe I'm just a bit tired. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't enough to show if $X_i$ $X_j$ are independent and continuous, then $Y = X_i - X_j$ is also continuous ?

Comment: @leonbloy I see, thank you!